# How to resolve this error?--index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning

[image]

Here's the image of my code. And the image I am trying to access via code is black and white.

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, _not_ images. The error means that `Y_train` is empty.

Comment: filelist_trainy = sorted(glob.glob('../Transfer/Datasets/ISIC2018_Task1-2_Training_GroundTruth/*.png'), key=numericalSort)
Y_train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist_trainy])                                        plt.imshow(Y_train[0])

Comment: I think this is because `filelist_trainy` is empty

Comment: Thank You very much, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check if Y_train is not an empty list and if so then get the first element

```
Y_train[0] if len(Y_train) > 0 else None
```

Because it seems from your code that it's empty.

Comment: but i have loaded the data

Comment: Thank you very much